# Why is polynomial fit not a good choice or a good extrapolation technique?

Tags: polynomials, least-squares, extrapolation

I would like to know why an polynomial fit is divergent on the boundaries of the fit interval (as shown on the doc site of the matlab polyfit function).
And why a polynomial fit on a data set is a very bad extrapolation technique for data just outside of the fit interval.

Method used to compute coefficients: least square method.

It seems that splines are better techniques for that but I try to understand why polynomial fits have these drawbacks.

Comment: With high degree polynomials, the fitted function would quickly shoot of to $\pm \infty$, which is often not wanted.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon

Comment: @VarunVejalla high degree polynomials could cause divergence just outside the fit interval, just after the upper bound ? Or could it be an overfitting problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Because every polynomial blows up at infinity, and the closer you get to infinity, the faster they blow up. Most real-world functions don't work like this.  For example, if you're trying to fit stock-market data, you probably want to assume a priori that there's a certain maximum size a company can grow to based on the size of its industry. Beyond that, it can't grow any further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, polynomial fitting is a very good technique if you do it right. For a very thorough explanation of why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn’t, look in Trefethen’s book “Approximation Theory and Practice”. Or see myth #1 in [these notes](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythstalk.pdf), or [this paper](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/mythspaper.pdf).